# Not able to replace String class using "-Xbootclasspath"

Tags: java, string

Just for my learning about `-Xbootclasspath`, I compiled a custom String class (modified the `toString` method to become `"return "Hey Sugar,: " + this;"`) and kept it in `C:/test/test2` and then create a simple Java program and used String as below:

```
        String str = new String("sss");
        System.out.println("############# " + str.toString());
```

Now, I compiled my test class and then ran it as `java -Xbootclasspath/p:test2/ MyTest` but I do not see the effect.

So, I am assuming my modified version of String class is not being loaded.

Am I doing something wrong?

Also, if I compile the keep the .class of modified String class in same folder as my test Java class then I get below error while trying to compile my test Java class.

```
MyTest.java:37: error: cannot access String
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                            ^
  bad class file: .\String.class
    class file contains wrong class: java.lang.String
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Comment: @MarianP Yes, for sure I have tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: your new String class needs to be in a directory `java/lang`

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer I hv already tried but it doesn't help.

Comment: Run `java` command with `-verbose:class` to see which String class is loaded.